# Sensor has interrupt pins. What can I connect them to?

Tags: microcontroller, interrupts, interface, pinout, peripheral-pin-select

I have a [BMI055](http://ae-bst.resource.bosch.com/media/products/dokumente/bmi055/BST-BMI055-DS000-08.pdf) gyroscope and accelerometer. on the sheet there is a section dedicated to the 4 interrupt pins (16,1,12,13 respective to 1,2,3, and 4). This section starts on page 30. and it seems that these pins are set to the high state whenever new data or a change is detected.

with a 4 pin SPI setup, is there a specific pin function that i need to connect it to on my microcontroller, or can I hook it up to an ExtINT (External interrupt) pin?

Comment: Dedicated interrupts are independent of SPI.  Depending on the architecture of your application you may or may not need to connect them to MCU interrupt pins; generally you would do so if you don't want to poll the sensor, or if you want to be able to sleep the MCU and wake it on a sensor condition.

Comment: @ChrisStratton this should actually be an answer! If i'm doing a constant reading (polling) of the accelerometer, then the interrups shouldn't be needed, correct?

Comment: Generally speaking, no, they shouldn't.  But this is the kind of area where reading the data sheets is ideally complemented by hand wiring a carrier for the sensor to an evaluation board for the selected micro-controller and verifying your ideas with test code, before you commit to a design choice.  Or, if you can afford the PCB real estate, you can hook up the interrupt lines via 0-ohm SMD resistors which you can install, or not, as needed.  Or even wire them up and never configure the interrupts if they prove unneeded.

Comment: @ChrisStrattonthe sensor is about as big as 1/2 a pinky nail. I don't have the resources to go and make an eval. board. I have more than enough pins on my MCU, should I connect them just to be safe?

Comment: If you can afford the pins, connect them.  If for some reason you aren't sure you will be able to simply ignore them in software, or might need to use the pins for something else, connect them via resistors you can install or not at later decision.  Incidentally, you may be able to find a generic breakout board for the sensor - especially if it is a QFN, perhaps less readily if it is an MSOP or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for motion control sensors, you can always constantly poll the data from your MCU, which will give you the highest sampling rate. However, there are situations where interrupts may be useful. A very common example is if you are using an accelerometer to detect the user interacting with the device (e.g. a remote control). You can put your MCU into some low power sleep state, and have it wake up only when the accelerometer asserts the interrupt pin corresponding to a large change in acceleration or orientation from user handling.

If your particular application only needs to read the acceleration/rotation at a constant sampling rate and you don't care about using it to wake up your MCU, you should not need to connect the interrupt pins. It may be prudent to connect them to external interrupt inputs on your MCU in case you want this feature later.

Comment: alright. to be even more prudent, could I connect it to an A/D converter, then use different resistor values to be able to use only one or 2 digital pins on my MCU, or is that more trouble than it's worth?

Comment: You could do this, but chances are if you need them, you will need them to trigger an interrupt on your MCU. I don't know of any MCUs which interrupt on a certain value from an A/D converter, and in any case, leaving the A/D converter would probably require as much power as the MCU itself.